# react boilerplate / generator with gulp, browserify, babel, etc?

Tags: reactjs

Is there a react.js boilerplate using official recommended tools from [facebook react](https://facebook.github.io/react/)? There is one from yeoman, however, [it](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit) uses web pack not browserify.

Comment: Create one. That's a good exercise.

Comment: @zerkms Yes, good advice. All existing boilerplates are not compatible with most current versions of babel, react, or react-router. So I created one [A simple example using babel 6.2 , webpack 1.12.6 , react 0.14.3, react-router 1.0.0](https://github.com/jma7889/babel6-webpack-react-router-static).

Answer (score 2):

This includes several projects using gulp, browserify and babel. Also reflux. https://github.com/calitek/ReactPatterns

Comment: thank you! If you don't mind, would you vote up my question so that I can have enough reputation to vote your answer?